# Fancy FAQS with Mootools 1.4.1?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools, mootools-more

This is a peice of code for creating a cool effect of FAQs using Mootools 1.2, I can't get it working with mootools 1.4.1. (even with compatibility on)

http://davidwalsh.name/flashy-faqs-mootools-sliders

Anyone have any ideas?

There is a jsFiddle of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicekiwi/VpT6D/3/ but jsFiddle appears to be having 'issues' atm, so im not sure how much help that will be.

The code seems to simple yet the problem.answer eludes me. Basicly it works, but when the question is clicked the answer opens but is hidden and the answer div expands to a disproportionate size to the answer it contains, eg 1500px and other weird CSS annomilies not present in the demo on that site I've linked.

Comment: if u put the js inside 'css' frame how can it work? ;) 1 min I ll tell u how to make it working with 1.4.1

Comment: Just a thought... wouldn't [Fx.Accordion](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Accordion) be much simpler in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here a possible solution : http://jsfiddle.net/xnV2N/

Comment: sigh, yes that works.. however not in my own code, which is essentially exactly the same. :(

Comment: But not EXACTLY the same, some lines of CSS were trying to position .question where they shouldn't, works all good now. Thank you